# Cygwin gdal library load error

Tags: cygwin, gdal

I built spatialite library then gdal library with spatialite support. Also built mapserver which depends on gdal with success. There was no problem with linking.

When I try to execute a gdal utility I get:

```
$ ogrinfo.exe
/usr/local/bin/ogrinfo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cyggdal-1.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

But everything seems fine:

```
$ ldd /usr/local/bin/ogrinfo.exe
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
        cyggdal-1.dll => /usr/local/bin/cyggdal-1.dll (0x710c0000)
        cygcurl-4.dll => /usr/bin/cygcurl-4.dll (0x63d80000)
        cyggcc_s-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-1.dll (0x67f00000)
        cygwin1.dll => /usr/bin/cygwin1.dll (0x61000000)
        ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x77dd0000)
        RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/RPCRT4.dll (0x77e70000)
        Secur32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/Secur32.dll (0x77fe0000)
        cygcrypto-0.9.8.dll => /usr/bin/cygcrypto-0.9.8.dll (0x6ba40000)
        cygidn-11.dll => /usr/bin/cygidn-11.dll (0x6c200000)
        cygiconv-2.dll => /usr/bin/cygiconv-2.dll (0x674c0000)
        cygintl-8.dll => /usr/bin/cygintl-8.dll (0x6f5c0000)
        cygssh2-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygssh2-1.dll (0x69ec0000)
        cygz.dll => /usr/bin/cygz.dll (0x692c0000)
        cygssl-0.9.8.dll => /usr/bin/cygssl-0.9.8.dll (0x63400000)
        cygexpat-1.dll => /usr/bin/cygexpat-1.dll (0x66ec0000)
        cyggeos_c-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggeos_c-1.dll (0x70180000)
        cyggeos-3-1-1.dll => /usr/bin/cyggeos-3-1-1.dll (0x4e0000)
        cygjpeg-7.dll => /usr/bin/cygjpeg-7.dll (0x66e00000)
        cygpng12.dll => /usr/bin/cygpng12.dll (0x6f200000)
```

If I copy the cyggdal-1.dll to the current folder:

```
$ ogrinfo.exe
/usr/local/bin/ogrinfo.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So what is a '?' library?

```
$ ldd cyggdal-1.dll
        ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
        kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
        ??? => ??? (0x710c0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x63d80000)
        ??? => ??? (0x67f00000)
        ??? => ??? (0x61000000)
        ??? => ??? (0x77dd0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x77e70000)
        ??? => ??? (0x77fe0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x6ba40000)
        ??? => ??? (0x6c200000)
        ??? => ??? (0x674c0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x6f5c0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x69ec0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x692c0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x63400000)
        ??? => ??? (0x66ec0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x70180000)
        ??? => ??? (0x4b0000)
        ??? => ??? (0x66e00000)
        ??? => ??? (0x6f200000)
```

What are these "???" ? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you build this program from source?  If so, please say how you built it.  If not, the question should be moved to Superuser, since it wouldn't be development related.

Comment: I built it. Although there were no errors it may be related with compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I used cmd to execute the utility and it showed a popup with the name of missing dll.